# Solutions of $x^2+y^2=1$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I want to find the number of unordered pairs $\{x,y\}\in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$.

I've found this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65183/when-is-the-sum-of-two-quadratic-residues-modulo-a-prime-again-a-quadratic-resid#) (#3) that solves this for the more general case of $ax^2+by^2=c$ mod $p$. Something worth noting is that my problem is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, so some solutions are counted twice and others only once, but unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to apply that to correctly count all solutions, it doesn't match what I get for small $p$s. Could you please help me understand how to apply that method to my problem? Also, if you find a more fundamental and simple way to solve this, please share (without projective geometry, I'm not familiar with it).
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $R=\mathbb{F}_p^2$. Define the product on $R$ by $(a,b) \cdot (c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc)$ and notice that it is commutative and associative.

You can have a better idea of $R$ by imagining that formally $(a,b)=a+ib$ with $i^2=-1$.

Let $f: R \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$ be defined by $f(a,b)=a^2+b^2$.

Note that $f$ is multiplicative and surjective.

Let $G$ be the set $f^{-1}(\mathbb{F}_p^*)$. Then $\mu: G \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a surjective group morphism. We actually want to determine the cardinality of the kernel of $\mu$, which is $k=\frac{|G|}{p-1}=\frac{p^2}{p-1}-\frac{|f^{-1}\{0\}|}{p-1}$.

So it just remains to study the fiber $f^{-1}\{0\}$.

If $p+1$ is divisible by $4$, then $-1$ isn’t a square mod $p$, from which it follows that $f(a,b)=0$ iff $a=b=0$. Therefore $k=\frac{p^2-1}{p-1}=p+1$.

If $p-1$ is divisible by $4$, then there is a square root of $-1$ (which we denote as $j$), and $a^2+b^2=0$ iff $(a+jb)(a-jb)=0$.

Now, it is easy to check that $g: \mathbb{F}_p^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p^2$ given by $g(a,b)=(a-jb,a+jb)$ is a bijection. Therefore, the cardinality of $f^{-1}\{0\}$ is that of $\{(a,b),\, ab=0\}$, which is thus $2p-1$. Hence, $k=\frac{p^2-(2p-1)}{p-1}=p-1$.

To summarize: the cardinality is $p+1$ if $p=3$ mod $4$, $p-1$ if $p=1$ mod $4$, $2$ if $p=2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
There is something I don’t quite understand yet: for $p=7$, I can only find $5$ and not $8$ ordered pairs: $(0,1);(0,6);(2,2);(2,5);(5,5)$ what am I missing here? Also, the construction you’re using for R is something like Cayley-Dickinson? (I think your last formula for k may have a LATEX typo).

Comment: You forgot: $(5,2)$, $(1,0)$ and $(6,0)$. I’m not too sure about naming the construction. Think of $R$ as the “complexified of $\mathbb{F}_p$”, ie you add a new square root of $-1$.

Comment: Actually, in ordered pairs $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are different objects. You seemingly want to count “unordered pairs”, which are better denoted as $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: For unordered pairs, there’s an added layer of subtlety because there are either (depending on whether $2$ is or not a square mod $p$) two or zero solutions that are symmetric. You need to study the different cases $p$ mod $8$ separately.

Comment: Yes, but those aren't ordered pairs, are they? The thing is, in my example, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ are basically the same, so I want to count them as one. We have to be careful about solutions of the type $2x^2=1$ but they only happen iff $2$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ so we have to split it into $3$ cases: if $p=1$ or $3$ mod $8$ then we have $\frac{p+1}{2}$; if $p=5$ mod $8$ then we have $\frac{p-1}{2}$; else, $p=7$ mod $8$ and we have $\frac{p+3}{2}$. Do you agree?

Comment: Oh sorry!! I meant unordered, then! I was writing my last comment as you were typing yours :)